# What is the correct format of a date for a Morris.js coffee file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, morris.js

I have the following .js.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
 Morris.Line
  element: 'averages_chart'
  data: [{month: '2014 01 01', average: 6}, {month: '2014 02 01', average: 5}]
  xkey: 'month'
  ykeys: ['average']
  labels: ['Average']
```

What is the correct date format to display the months correctly?

None of these seem to work properly

```
month: '2014 01 01'
month: 2014/01/01
month: '2014/01/01'
month: 'Jan 2014'
```

Here is a js bin example: http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?javascript,live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the [official documentation](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html)

> Timestamps are accepted in the form of millisecond timestamps (as
>   returned by Date.getTime() or as strings in the following formats:
>
> ```
> 2012
> 2012 Q1
> 2012 W1
> 2012-02
> 2012-02-24
> 2012-02-24 15:00
> 2012-02-24 15:00:00
> 2012-02-24 15:00:00.000
> ```
>
> Note: when using millisecond timestamps, it's recommended that you
>   check out the dateFormat option. Note 2: date/time strings can
>   optionally contain a T between the date and time parts, and/or a Z
>   suffix, for compatibility with ISO-8601 dates.

Just replace slashes by hyphens, and it should be ok